# SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE happens randomly, when trying to pull data from different APIs (Shopify, Klaviyo)

Tags: python, ssl, shopify, shopify-api, klaviyo

Over the last few days we have noticed API errors from 2 different APIs, Shopify and Klaviyo,

For Shopify, the weird thing is that it happens only when we pull `Product` and `Product` related information, **SOMETIMES**, and some other times it just works.

For Klaviyo, it can happen on any entity, but similar issue is here: It may happen **SOMETIMES**, and usually it works.

We have noticed that it fails at some point when we pull data for some time (e.g. when we pull a list of products from Shopify or a list of members from Klaviyo).

We are using python 3.10 for both cases. For Shopify, we use the [official python client](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) to access the API, and for Klaviyo we are using custom implementation with tornado async HTTP agent.

Example error from Shopify:

This one occurs when we pull `CustomCollection` entity by id

```
...
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 196, in find
  collection = super(ShopifyResource, cls).find(id_=id_, from_=from_, **kwargs)
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 386, in find
  return cls._find_every(from_=from_, **kwargs)
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 525, in _find_every
  response = cls.connection.get(path, cls.headers)
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 329, in get
  return self._open('GET', path, headers=headers)
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 23, in _open
  self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 290, in _open
  raise Error(err, url)
 pyactiveresource.connection.Error: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)>
```

We get similar errors when pulling `Product` or `InventoryItem`, for example, but usually not when pulling `Customer` or `Order` data.

Example error from Klaviyo:

```
 File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 767, in run
  value = future.result()
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 340, in run
  stream = await self.tcp_client.connect(
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/tcpclient.py", line 292, in connect
  stream = await stream.start_tls(
File "/home/airflow/.local/.virtualenvs/agents310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1367, in _do_ssl_handshake
  self.socket.do_handshake()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
  self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)
```

Those has started to occur very recently. We have not changed anything to our procedure that pulls data, neither to the software of it.

Some googling indicates that there is some mismatch during the TLS handshake because of unsupported ciphers in either the server or the client.

But I am not sure that this is the issue here, because:

- This seems to happen randomly, and mostly when pulling Product and Product-related data (for Shopify)
- We can pull Customer and Order data in most cases, if not always, using similar procedure and software (for Shopify)
- Same for Klaviyo, we start pulling some data, then at some point there is this SSL error
  I have tried some of the failed request using cURL, and they succeed, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with a particular endpoint, but something different
- I have checked the TLS versions that are supported by our OpenSSL and they seems legitimate (`TLSv1.3` is supported)

So if this was indeed cipher issue, I'd expect that it would not work, at all. But here this works most of the time.

From within the server that we run that:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.3
```

and from the python instance:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
OpenSSL 1.1.1n 15 Mar 2022
```

Note that the same thing occurs for different Shopify stores (from different clients of ours). Same for Klaviyo, occurs for a different number of clients (hence different accounts).

Do you have any ideas / suggestion why this may happen?

Could it be something else, irrelevant from the TLS handshake? E.g. some server issue or API limits (I know they should return a 429 status, but you never know with custom implementations today)?

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: *I know they should return a 429 status*  No.  A 429 is an **HTTP** response code, and if your SSL connection fails, the connection hasn't even reached the point where an HTTP request an be sent for you to get an HTTP response.  Is there any chance you're being subjected to a MITM attack?

Comment: _if your SSL connection fails, the connection hasn't even reached the point where an HTTP request an be sent for you to get an HTTP response_ - yes, makes absolute sense. Well, I find it hard to be under MITM attack since we run those on AWS cloud behind firewalls, so unless someone has managed to sneak into our VPC this case seems out of question I think?